# Can I design a webPAGE with asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I work with c# for a while now for programming.And I know this may be a stupid question,but is it possible to design a webpage(not a web app)using c# in asp?and if yes,where can I begin from?

Comment: First off: why not just use HTML directly? Using ASP syntax for this is just needlessly clunky and you lose all the knowhow available for HTML. Second off: it's exactly the same as making an `.aspx` view for a webapp. Just don't make it do anything dynamic. Also you'll still have to run this in IIS so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please elaborate - can you explain what you think the difference is between a "web page" and a "web app" (in reality, one encompasses the other).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

a basic HTML page with `.aspx` extension is also runnable with IIS

You might also want to look into razor and developing a front end with it.

See webmatrix from Microsoft and don't forget to look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: Using Razor requires a controller and associated action logic.

Comment: @Dai I've used Razor without a controller or all the MVC stuff - webmatrix

Comment: @Dai Nope. There's a slightly obscure branch of ASP.NET called "Web Pages" where Razor is used as just a template engine with a bunch of functionality for quick-and-dirty dynamism.

Comment: You shouldn't really link to w3schools as a reference site. See: http://w3fools.com/ The MDN docs might be a better place to learn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: @Dai just like you do not need webforms to run .aspx files, you don't need mvc pattern and all the controllers to run a .cshtml file

Comment: @Aniket my mistake - I forgot about ASP.NET WebPages. However using *.aspx files directly always invokes WebForms, even if you haven't defined a code-behind class.

Comment: @Brandon, I agree with you but sometimes for starters, W3Schools works better than MDN. I'll suggest go MDN first, when confused, try W3Schools to understand then get back to MDN to verify.

Comment: @RayCheng W3Schools has good PR and is written in a way that's easy for beginners to understand, despite being incorrect or providing just poor advice - this is a real problem that MDN and other sites have.

Comment: Look guys,thanks for your replys,but I am confused here.you see,I want to start designing web pages and I am hoping that my c# knowledge helps me!But I have no idea how and where to start.I just need a starting point.thanks again

Comment: designing webpages - Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 for drag and drop, but I suggest you learn from books on HTML5 and CSS, touching upon asp.net as and when you want. Also see Javascript and JQuery @user2078785